# Replacing atom in Hydrocarbon Molecule

Tags: hydrocarbons

I am working with Hydrocarbons. In some of me analysis I see that carbon atoms are replaced with oxygen or other elements, like this one [image].
Me question is: is only the carbon atom can be replaced or the hydrogen can be also be replaced?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "can be replaced". Are you asking about whether we can have molecules which have some atoms replaced with others? Or about specific reactions to cause such a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hydrogen atoms can be replaced with other atoms with a valence of one, like Chlorine and other halogens. This gives a family of substances called [haloalkanes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haloalkane).

Another option is a group of atoms like -OH: this gives [alcohol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol).